# spring boot mvc ajax call with a loading

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have a spring boot mvc application. My requirement is when i hit a url like this
localhost:8080/myproject/getData

It should show a loading gif and do a ajax call to the spring mvc controller and return the result "ok" to the caller. Could anyone give a sample code or some idea on implementing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 controllers.

`@Controller` will be responsible for returning the page with loading gif (it can be Thymeleaf, JSP, or whatever), that HTML "view" returned by MVC `@Controller` will contain JavaScript with your AJAX implementation (jQuery, AngularJS, or whatever), that will make an AJAX call to your `@RestController`, requesting JSON/XML data (the URL has to be different e.g. "/myproject/api").

Then on your success method you will replace the loading GIF with your data from `@RestController` (the result "ok").

Comment: So on the view I have to show the loading gif and same time I have to make a rest ajax call to the rest controller ?

Comment: If you want to show GIF, that will fill the time of waiting for your main data, yes.

Comment: For a single request you can get one response, with one type of data, so you have to make two.